# Salesforce: Execute python script through Apex class

Tags: salesforce

I have a custom button in Salesforce and a python script which takes the data from Accounts table, perform some logic and save it in an object (a different table).

I want to execute python script by clicking the custom button. Hence, is there any way to execute the python script through Apex class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run the Python on Salesforce so you'll need to run it somewhere else like Heroku.  Then when the button is clicked you'll need to send the data to the Python app via something like a Webhook or Apex callout.

Comment: OK. I have Centos where i can run python and can write Javascript(JS) code behind a custom button to call an Apex class. Can you let me know what should i write in the Apex class (a basic example) so that it calls the python script sitting at the server end?